# SwipeRefreshLayout interfering with setOnScrollListener

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout, onscrolllistener

Everytime I scroll the list up or down I hide (or unhide) some views with `OnScrollListener`.  Here is the code attached to my `ListView`.

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;
            private boolean mIsScrollingUp = true;
            private LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) getActivity()
                    .findViewById(R.id.llSearchPlaces);

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {



                if (view.getId() == lv.getId()) {
                    final int currentFirstVisibleItem = lv
                            .getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {

                        if (mIsScrollingUp == true) {
                            mIsScrollingUp = false;
                             Log.i("a", "scrolling down...");

                            floatingActionButton.hide();

                            Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                                    0, 200);
                            animation.setDuration(300);
                            animation
                                    .setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onAnimationEnd(
                                                Animation animation) {
                                            ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onAnimationRepeat(
                                                Animation animation) {
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onAnimationStart(
                                                Animation animation) {
                                        }
                                    });

                            ll.startAnimation(animation);
                        }

                    } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {

                        if (mIsScrollingUp == false) {
                            mIsScrollingUp = true;
                            floatingActionButton.show();
                             Log.i("a", "scrolling up...");

                            Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                                    200, 0);
                            animation.setDuration(400);
                            animation
                                    .setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onAnimationEnd(
                                                Animation animation) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onAnimationRepeat(
                                                Animation animation) {

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onAnimationStart(
                                                Animation animation) {
                                            ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        }
                                    });

                            ll.startAnimation(animation);

                        }
                    }

                    mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;

                }
            }
        });
```

**Layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Ever since I added the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, I do not get anything when I `Log` inside the listener above.  How can I use both of these items together?

**EDIT**:  It seems like [this](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-swiperefreshlayout-tutorial.html) is what I need but I can't make it work still

As part of that article I added this in `onScroll`, tho it doesn't seem to work.

```
        if (firstVisibleItem == 0) {
            swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            swipeLayout.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

**EDIT2**:  THIS IS THE HEART OF THE ISSUE: It seems the `onScroll` method fires when the Activity first starts and the list loads and then never more again.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with `RecyclerView` and `ListView`. Scrolling downwards for whatever amount of items, it was impossible to return to the top of the list.

This will disable the `SwipeRefreshLayout` until the first visible item or any item position is visible. You can also bind different scroll listeners along this one. Make sure you enable (if previously disabled) `SwipeRefreshLayout` whenever you repopulate the listivew.

```
public class SwipeRefreshLayoutToggleScrollListenerListView implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private List<AbsListView.OnScrollListener> mScrollListeners = new ArrayList<AbsListView.OnScrollListener>();
    private int mExpectedVisiblePosition = 0;

    public SwipeRefreshLayoutToggleScrollListenerListView(SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeLayout) {
        this.mSwipeLayout = mSwipeLayout;
    }

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeLayout;
    public void addScrollListener(AbsListView.OnScrollListener listener){
        mScrollListeners.add(listener);
    }
    public boolean removeScrollListener(AbsListView.OnScrollListener listener){
        return mScrollListeners.remove(listener);
    }
    public void setExpectedFirstVisiblePosition(int position){
        mExpectedVisiblePosition = position;
    }

    private void notifyOnScrolled(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){
        for(AbsListView.OnScrollListener listener : mScrollListeners){
            listener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
        }
    }
    private void notifyScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState){
        for(AbsListView.OnScrollListener listener : mScrollListeners){
            listener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
      notifyScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        notifyOnScrolled(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
        if(firstVisibleItem != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
            mSwipeLayout.setEnabled(firstVisibleItem == mExpectedVisiblePosition);
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new SwipeRefreshLayoutToggleScrollListenerListView(mSwiperLayout){
   //override methods here, don't forget the super calls. 
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Still struggling on this one.  On the methods above that are NOT `Override`'s, where do they need to be called?   This is where I am at: When the Activity starts, it immediately calls the `onScrollStateChanged` (not sure why -- I guess populating the list?) and it will enable the SwipeLayout.  Then when I manually scroll the list, up or down, it is not being called.  I can't disable the layout if it is never called.  Also, i am not `implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener`.  I am just using an anonymous inner `class`.

Comment: If I got you right,you are concerned about the usage, see my edit. You are still able to override methods even when you don't have anonymous instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I actually had it that way.  Not sure why I actually brought that part up.  What I did notice, the methods you provided that are not overriden, I don't see them used except for `notifyScrollStateChanged`.  Wondering if that is why I haven't figured this one out yet.

Comment: You can remove these methods if you don't need them. They are used if you want to have more than one scroll listener for one `ListView`

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. Still working on this one.  Unable to work it out yet with this code... will keep you updated

Answer (score 2):

```
yourListview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            boolean enable = false;
            if(timelogListView != null && timelogListView.getChildCount() > 0){
                boolean firstItemVisible = timelogListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
                boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = timelogListView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
                enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
            }
            swipeLayout.setEnabled(enable); 
            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                if(flag_loading == false)
                {
                    flag_loading = true;
                    ConnectionDetector conn = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());
                    if(conn.isConnectingToInternet()){
                        // call for your pagination async
                    }else{

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

### By default : private boolean flag_loading = false; and in your pagination async if(YourListview.size() < 20) { flag_loading = true; } else{ flag_loading = false; }

Comment: This seems like you are assuming I am using a paginated `ListView` that scrolls endlessly.  It is not, it is a fixed size.

Answer (score 2):

You should override [`canChildScrollUp`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#canChildScrollUp()) of `SwipeRefreshView`. This method is polled for the purpose of knowing whether the contained View wants to scroll up:

An extension with a settable interface for any arbritrary contained view:

```
public class SwipeRefreshWrapper extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    private ScrollResolver mScrollResolver;

    public SwipeRefreshWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SwipeRefreshWrapper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setScrollResolver(ScrollResolver scrollResolver) {
        mScrollResolver = scrollResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        if(mScrollResolver != null){
            return mScrollResolver.canScrollUp();
        }else {
            return super.canChildScrollUp();
        }
    }

    public static interface ScrollResolver{
        public boolean canScrollUp();
    }
}
```

Usage (`ListView` also has a nice method: `canScrollVertically()`):

```
final SwipeRefreshWrapper wrapper = (SwipeRefreshWrapper) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
final ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

wrapper.setScrollResolver(new SwipeRefreshWrapper.ScrollResolver() {
                              @Override
                              public boolean canScrollUp() {
                                 return list.canScrollVertically(-1);
                              }
                          });
```